# Definition of the sheaf of differentials.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a $K$-scheme. The sheaf of relative differentials of $X$ over $K$ is the sheaf $\Omega_{X/K}$ such that restricted to an open affine subset $U=Spec(A)$ satisfies:
$$
\Omega_{X/K}|_U\simeq (\Omega_{A/K})^\sim.
$$

Now, if I am not wrong, it is the cotangent sheaf. Hence, it should be the sheaf of sections of the line bundle given by:
$$
L=\{(p,\alpha):p\in X, \alpha\in\frac{\mathfrak{m}_p}{\mathfrak{m}_p^2}\}.
$$

Are these definitions indeed equivalent?

Comment: Theorem 3.15 in these notes might be useful: http://people.math.sfu.ca/~kya17/teaching/math800/MATH%20800%20-%20Final%20Project.pdf It basically says that the fibres of the sheaf are isomorphic to $m/m^2$. These needn't have the same dimension (i.e., it needn't be a vector bundle)! In this setting the sheaf will be locally free of rank $\dim X$ if the scheme is smooth over $k$, for example (not sure if the converse holds).